# Using Python String Formatting with Lists

Tags: python, string, list, formatting, string-formatting

I construct a string `s` in Python 2.6.5 which will have a varying number of `%s` tokens, which match the number of entries in list `x`. I need to write out a formatted string. The following doesn't work, but indicates what I'm trying to do. In this example, there are three `%s` tokens and the list has three entries.

```
s = '%s BLAH %s FOO %s BAR'
x = ['1', '2', '3']
print s % (x)
```

I'd like the output string to be:

`1 BLAH 2 FOO 3 BAR`

Comment: related: [Formatted string literals in Python 3.6 with tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38763895/10197418) in case you're looking for an f-string based solution.

Answer (score 129, accepted):

```
print s % tuple(x)
```

instead of

```
print s % (x)
```

Comment: `(x)` is the same thing as `x`. Putting a single token in brackets has no meaning in Python. You usually put brackets in `foo = (bar, )` to make it easier to read but `foo = bar,` does exactly the same thing.

Comment: `print s % (x)` is what OP wrote, I was just quoting him/her.

Comment: I was just providing a language tip, not criticizing your answer (in fact I +1'd it). You did not write `foo = (bar, )` either :)

Comment: I use the `(x)` notation for clarity; it also avoids forgetting the brackets if you later add additional variables.

Comment: How about if you want to source your variables from multiple lists?  tuple only takes a single list, and the formatter seems to only take a single tuple

Comment: Answered my own question: `print s % (tuple(x) + tuple(y))`

Comment: This is the best answer! It's much simpler and shorter than the `.format()` one, which  is undeservedly the most upvoted one!!

Answer (score 193):

You should take a look to the [format](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) method of python. You could then define your formatting string like this :

```
>>> s = '{0} BLAH BLAH {1} BLAH {2} BLAH BLIH BLEH'
>>> x = ['1', '2', '3']
>>> print s.format(*x)
'1 BLAH BLAH 2 BLAH 3 BLAH BLIH BLEH'
```

Comment: The OP's problem is not the method but the format of the parameters. `%` operator only unpacks tuples.

Comment: This would make the construction of `s` more complex, as I would need to include incrementing numbers rather than simply `%s` for each position. `s` is built up in a number of different steps, so it's much easier to just include the `%s` token.

Comment: @SabreWolfy If you construct it precedurally then you might find it easier to name your placeholders and use a dict to format the resulting string: `print u'%(blah)d BLAHS %(foo)d FOOS …' % {'blah': 15, 'foo': 4}`.

Comment: @SabreWolfy: In Python 2.7, you can omit the field numbers: `s = '{} BLAH {} BLAH BLAH {} BLAH BLAH BLAH'`

Comment: This answer is potentially confusing, as it makes it look like the numerical values of 0, 1 and 2 are somehow related to the number of times the word "BLAH" appears.

Comment: @SabreWolfy edit my answer to avoid repetitions and potential confusion

Comment: What is the meaning, or function, of the asterisk (*) ?

Comment: @kotchwane : the * function is a special python keyword that transform an argument that is a list into a list of arguements :). In our case, *x will pass to the format method the 3 members of x.

Answer (score 45):

Following this [resource page](https://sites.google.com/site/kittipat/programming-with-python/formatanddisplayelementsinpythonlist), if the length of x is varying, we can use:

```
', '.join(['%.2f']*len(x))
```

to create a place holder for each element from the list `x`. Here is the example:

```
x = [1/3.0, 1/6.0, 0.678]
s = ("elements in the list are ["+', '.join(['%.2f']*len(x))+"]") % tuple(x)
print s
>>> elements in the list are [0.33, 0.17, 0.68]
```

Answer (score 30):

**Here is a one liner. A little improvised answer using format with print() to iterate a list.**

How about this (python 3.x):

```
sample_list = ['cat', 'dog', 'bunny', 'pig']
print("Your list of animals are: {}, {}, {} and {}".format(*sample_list))
```

Read the docs here on using [format()](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/).

Comment: What is the meaning, or function, of the asterisk (*) ? Your link to the documentation does not seem to clarify that.

Comment: @kotchwane the asterisk "expands" the list as individual ordered arguments. f(\*x) == f(x[0], x[1], ..., x[n]). Similarly, two asterisks (\*\*) expands a dict to keyword arguments.

Answer (score 22):

Since I just learned about this cool thing(indexing into lists from within a format string) I'm adding to this old question.

```
s = '{x[0]} BLAH {x[1]} FOO {x[2]} BAR'
x = ['1', '2', '3']
print (s.format (x=x))
```

Output:

```
1 BLAH 2 FOO 3 BAR
```

However, I still haven't figured out how to do slicing(inside of the format string `'"{x[2:4]}".format...`,) and would love to figure it out if anyone has an idea, however I suspect that you simply cannot do that.

Comment: I am a little curious about your use case for slicing.

Comment: i dont really have one ... i think i just thought it would be neat to be able to do

Comment: Note that you can also do: `'{0[0]} BLAH {0[1]} FOO {0[2]} BAR'.format(x)`. In other words, you do not need to name the argument.

Answer (score 12):

This was a fun question! Another way to handle this **for variable length lists** is to build a function that takes full advantage of the `.format` method and list unpacking. In the following example I don't use any fancy formatting, but that can easily be changed to suit your needs.

```
list_1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
list_2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

# Create a function that can apply formatting to lists of any length:
def ListToFormattedString(alist):
    # Create a format spec for each item in the input `alist`.
    # E.g., each item will be right-adjusted, field width=3.
    format_list = ['{:>3}' for item in alist] 

    # Now join the format specs into a single string:
    # E.g., '{:>3}, {:>3}, {:>3}' if the input list has 3 items.
    s = ','.join(format_list)

    # Now unpack the input list `alist` into the format string. Done!
    return s.format(*alist)

# Example output:
>>>ListToFormattedString(list_1)
'  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6'
>>>ListToFormattedString(list_2)
'  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8'
```

Answer (score 6):

For just filling in an arbitrary list of values to a string, you could do the following, which is the same as @neobot's answer but a little more modern and succinct.

```py
>>> l = range(5)
>>> " & ".join(["{}"]*len(l)).format(*l)
'0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4'
```

If what you are concatenating together is already some kind of structured data, I think it would be better to do something more like:

```py
>>> data = {"blah": 1, "foo": 2, "bar": 3}
>>> " ".join([f"{k} {v}" for k, v in data.items()])
'blah 1 foo 2 bar 3'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
x = ['1', '2', '3']
s = f"{x[0]} BLAH {x[1]} FOO {x[2]} BAR"
print(s)
```

The output is

```
1 BLAH 2 FOO 3 BAR
```