# Join the same argument mulitple times from list

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask

I'm dynamically generating a list of check boxes using values from a list as follows:

```
return flask.jsonify(result='\n'.join('<input type="checkbox" class="av-sources">%s<br>'% src for src in my_list))
```

The problem I am facing is, when trying to include a list item multiple times:

For Ex:

```
.join('<input type="checkbox" class="av-sources" value="%s">%s<br>'% src for src in my_list))
```

i know src is not referenced mulitple times, i dont have it in a tuple (item1, item2) so I get the following error:

```
TypeError: TypeError('not enough arguments for format string',) is not JSON serializable
```

I dont know how to reference the string twice when using % src for src in my_list)).

I have tried switching to `value="{0}">{0}<br>.format(src for src in my_list))`

but the code does not iterate through my list and only returns one object

> < i n p u t t y p e = " c h e c k b o x " c l a s s = " a v - s o u r
>   c e s " v a l u e = " < g e n e r a t o r o b j e c t < g e n e x p r
>
> > a t 0 x 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 1 E D 9 0 0 > " > < g e n e r a t o r o b j e c t < g e n e x p r > a t 0 x 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 1 E D 9 0 0 >
> >     < b r >

my function is here:

```
@app.route("/_srcs")
def source():


    try:
        source_txt = a JSON Blob
        source_load = json.loads(source_txt)
        sources = []
        for i in source_load['sources']:
            sources.append(i['name'])

        return flask.jsonify(result='\n'.join('<input type="checkbox" class="av-sources" value="{0}">{0}<br>'.format(src for src in sources)))

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return flask.jsonify(error=e)
```

Here is my javascript:

```
$(function() {
var pythonsources = function(e) {
    console.log('kibi sources');
  $.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + '/_srcs', {

  }, function(data) {

    $('#sources').html(data.result);
  });
  return false;
};
$('#menu-toggle2').bind('click', pythonsources );
});
```

If someone can point me in the right direction, thanks

Comment: Try this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7568627/using-python-string-formatting-with-lists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you just have a bracket in the wrong place.

Change...

```
'\n'.join('<input type="checkbox" class="av-sources" value="{0}">{0}<br>'.format(src for src in sources))
```

...to...

```
'\n'.join('<input type="checkbox" class="av-sources" value="{0}">{0}<br>'.format(src) for src in sources)
```