# Formatted string literals in Python 3.6 with tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples, string-formatting, python-3.6

With `str.format()` I can use tuples for accesing arguments:

```
>>> '{0}, {1}, {2}'.format('a', 'b', 'c')

'a, b, c'
```

or

```
>>> t = ('a', 'b', 'c')
>>> '{0}, {1}, {2}'.format(*t)

'a, b, c'
```

But with the new formatted string literals prefixed with 'f' (f-strings), how can I use tuples?

```
f'{0}, {1}, {2}'.(*t)  # doesn't work
```

Comment: What you mean by *But with the new formatted string literals prefixed with 'f' how can use tuples*? Also in your second sample you need to unpack the tuple.

Comment: Usage of f-strings depends a lot on the particular use case. Give us a realistic example on what you're trying to do, since the current problem would be best done with `', '.join(t)` in both 3.6 and pre-3.6

Comment: `'...'.format('a', 'b', 'c')` is a **method call**, one you called with 3 arguments. You did not pass in a tuple in your first example. In your second example, you are using the `*args` call syntax; `str.format()` still receives 3 separate arguments and doesn't know you used a tuple to supply those.

Comment: @Kasramvd I mean that  `f'{0}, {1}, {2}'.(*t)` doesn't works

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your first `str.format()` call is a regular method call with 3 arguments, there is *no tuple involved there*. Your second call uses the `*` splat call syntax; the `str.format()` call receives 3 separate individual arguments, it doesn't care that those came from a tuple.

Formatting strings with `f` don't use a method call, so you can't use either technique. Each slot in a `f'..'` formatting string is instead executed as a regular Python expression.

You'll have to extract your values from the tuple directly:

```
f'{t[0]}, {t[1]}, {t[2]}'
```

or first expand your tuple into new local variables:

```
a, b, c = t
f'{a}, {b}, {c}'
```

or simply continue to use `str.format()`. You don't *have* to use an `f'..'` formatting string, this is a *new, additional feature* to the language, not a replacement for `str.format()`.

From [PEP 498 -- *Literal String Interpolation*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/):

> This PEP does not propose to remove or deprecate any of the existing string formatting mechanisms.

Comment: `f'Values: {str(t)[1:-2]}'` ftw. No but seriously, new ways might end up popping from nowhere, based on the use case. I don't think this question can be answered too generally

Comment: `str.format()` will not be deprecated in Python 3.6?

Comment: No, I'm pretty certain it'll never go away during Python 3. @Trimax

Comment: @Trimax: no, not at all. formatting strings are an **additional** feature, not a replacement.

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen: That'll still include the quotes. Why not `', '.join(t)`?

Comment: Indeed, that's what I suggested under comments for the original question too! @MartijnPieters The point I was trying to make is that there might not be one-to-one way of converting `.format()` to f-strings, but completely different ways will be discovered... And sometimes `.format()` is still the best option.