# TypeError: not enough arguments for format string when using %s and a python dictionary

Tags: python, mysql-python

I've printed the output of my "payload" which I want to save to the MySQL database:

```
('B01MTOV8IP', '40462', '23.95', 'n/a', 'Usually ships in 24 hours', 
'https://www.amazon.com/reviews/iframe?akid=AKIAIDCPAFSAQICDTFNQ&alinkCode=xm2&asin=B01MTOV8IP&atag=reakenture-20&exp=2017-08-25T17%3A27%3A37Z&v=2&sig=3zbBXVo4cQAJueFeVeo%252F%252FejvaUOmvuwAtfB4EfMyDiU%253D', 'CHG-GSTWL')
```

There seems to be something wrong with the way I am formatting it before I pass it to connect.

```
try:
    selling_price = product.price_and_currency
    selling_price_v = selling_price[0]#type
    print selling_price_v
except Exception as e:
    selling_price = "n/a"

conn = MySQLdb.connect(host="clabadmin.cfcudy1fdz8o.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com", user="", passwd="", db="")
payload =[
asin,
bsr,
str(selling_price_v),
str(listing_price_v),
# availability_type,
availability,
reviews,
sku]
print payload 
# conn = sqlite3.connect('skubsr.db')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("""UPDATE webservice_bsr 
SET 
AISN = %s,
Best_Sellers_Rank = %s,
selling_price =  %s,
price = %s,
# availability_type = %s,
availability = %s,
reviews = %s
WHERE ItemSKU = %s""", payload)
conn.commit()
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/trackstarz/clabReportScraper/bsrimport.py", line 907, in <module>
    WHERE ItemSKU = %s""", payload)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 187, in execute
    query = query % tuple([db.literal(item) for item in args])
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
[Finished in 3.1s with exit code 1]
```

Comment: Why do you think the hash will do anything in the query?

Comment: I deleted it and same error

Comment: You have 8 occurrences of `%s` in your query, but `payload` has only 7 elements. A `#` doesn't comment out part of the query; it would simply produce a syntax error if `c.execute` actually tried to send it to the database.

Answer (score 1):

`#` is only used to indicate a comment when used inside Python code. In your query, it is inside the query string, and so is not parsed as a comment identifier, but as part of the query.

If you delete it, you are left with 8 `%s` and only 7 items inside `payload`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is you have multiple %s string indicators in your execute string but are only giving it a single item (in this case a list) which it doesn't know it should break down into multiple values.

Try using some of the suggestions in this post to get your desired effect.

[Using Python String Formatting with Lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7568627/using-python-string-formatting-with-lists)

Comment: No, the `execute()` method knows how to handle the sequence.