# Replace substring in a string using a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm looking for a more pythonic way to replace a known length of placeholders in a string with the values found in a list. They should replace in order and only be used once. For example with the values:

```
replaceVals = ['foo', 'bar']

origStr = 'I went to the ? to get ?'
```

I am looking to get:

```
newStr = 'I went to the foo to get bar'
```

I was able to get the desired result with the following loop, but I feel like there should be a better way to go about this than using a loop like so.

```
for i in range(len(replaceVals)):
   origStr = origStr.replace('?', replaceVals[i], 1)
```

Comment: `origStr = 'I went to the {} to get {}'.format(*replaceVals)`

Comment: This has to be a dupe but the closest I can find is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4450592/is-there-a-python-equivalent-to-rubys-string-interpolation and it misses the most basic usage

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Python String Formatting with Lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7568627/using-python-string-formatting-with-lists)

Comment: Do people get points for trying to point out duplicates? Just curious. Seems to be a real desire of late to not allow anything near a duplicate. I certainly don't want SO filled with the exact same question 100 times, but I don't mind 3 or 4 of pretty similar questions, just because it helps others with similar problems triangulate their own better.

Comment: @TravisGriggs no, but what's the point of having information rehashed in like 3 or 4 lines (which is becoming typical - "you can try this: <code>") when there is a single source of definitive info?

Comment: @TravisGriggs ... case in point

Comment: I guess I don't see @roganjosh. Like coding, I reduce/combine/refactor common patterns, once they've matured and I can prove that they really are. Premature "this looks like it's gonna be that" before it's matured, doesn't work for me.

Comment: @TravisGriggs What I'm suggesting is that the answer offers no explanation of why you should use the method proposed. The duplicate serves its purpose by directing different search terms to a particular source that I think provides some context for future viewers. We may disagree on this, fine, but it went exactly as I said: "Here's a way to do it"

Comment: I like your answer, just been burned too many times on SO lately where I post a question and someone slaps down the "looks like a duplicate folks" and often kills the chance of anyone looking at it any further. The "no, I went and looked at it and let me clarify why my case is different" ends up being too late.

Comment: @roganjosh This solution will work only if `origStr` does not contain a literal `{}`, in which case additional steps are needed to escape it.

Comment: @TravisGriggs, maybe SO can have 3 types of dups: **1**. easy-to-find exact dups, should be downvoted and closed; **2**. hard-to-find exact dups, should be just closed with a reference link with no penalty to OP, some of us come to SO because we lack a certain knowledge, and due to lack of that very same knowledge, we couldn't recognize our questions were dups.; **3**. similar questions, still worth discussing with reference links to similar questions under it, think it as teachers giving students practice problems of slight variations but testing the same concept.

Comment: Works for me @Indomimus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `replace` and `format` methods of the string as shown below:

```
origStr.replace('?','{}').format(*replaceVals)

Out[334]: 'I went to the foo to get bar'
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an idea using *generators*:

```
replaceVals = iter(['foo', 'bar'])
origStr = 'I went to the ? to get ?'

(' ').join(next(replaceVals) if i == '?' else i for i in origStr.split())
```

**Output:**

```
'I went to the foo to get bar'
```

---

The advantage of doing it this way, is that the amount of items in `replaceVals` does not have to match the amount of items to be replaced in `origStr`:

```
replaceVals = iter(['foo', 'bar', 'other'])
origStr = 'I went to the ? to get ?'

(' ').join(next(replaceVals) if i == '?' else i for i in origStr.split())
#'I went to the foo to get bar'
```

However using string formatting would cause errors under these circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

@roganjosh 's answer in comments is possibly the best, though the OP is abstract enough that it's not clear what his real case is. I was curious whether one could do this with f-strings which showed up in Python3. What makes an f-string less appealing than @roganjosh's, is that it's just so easy to unpack the replacement sequence through the `.format()` call. That said, *IF* you wanted to try an f-string, something like this would work:

```
replaceVals = ['foo', 'bar'] 
stream = iter(replaceVals)
f'I went to the {stream.next()} to get {stream.next()}'
```

Answer (score 0):

f string

```
r=["foo","bar"]
origStr = f'I went to the {r[0]} to get {r[1]}'

origStr
Out[21]: 'I went to the foo to get bar'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string with `'?'`, then use `itertools.zip_longest` to pair substrings in the resulting list with replacement strings in `replaceVals` with an empty string as a fill value, and join the pairs of strings after flattening them with a generator expression:

```
from itertools import zip_longest
''.join(i for p in zip_longest(origStr.split('?'), replaceVals, fillvalue='') for i in p)
```